# Specified node in "torrc"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I've learned that it is possible to specify the Entry node and Exit node in "torrc". However, I do not know how to specify the intermediate node. Is there a way to specify an intermediate node in "torrc"? How do I set if any?